# HTML element percentage height problem

Tags: html, css, elasticlayout

i made  myself a Speed Dial-like homepage with links I visit the most.
Now, i made it elastic, so when browser window is narrowed horizontally, the boxes getting narrower too.

What I want is that when browser window is narrowed vertically, that boxes get narrower again.

I tried with several percentage height rules but it didn't work, need help.

Here is the page I'm working on its one-file page so CSS is not separated.
http://www.purplerspace.com/dl/

Comment: What exactly is the problem you ran into with the percentage heights?

Comment: it doesn't work simply put, boxes don't scale horizontally when browser window is resized horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the height percentages to almost all the divs if you want it to work. Add height: 100% to html, body then the wrappers and also the lis and yeah, the a style too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's optimal but tables for this should work. Set the table height and width to 100%. And don't forget to set your html and wrapper tag to 100% in height.